# pcap frame content to chars in Erlang

Tags: erlang, pcap

I have pcap frame content in below format:

```
[{frame,1,
    {1491,213,861700},
    87,87,false,
    <<1,0,94,0,0,251,0,80,86,192,0,8,8,0,69,0,0,73,68,44,0,0,255,17,18,
      106,172,16,216,1,224,0,0,251,20,233,20,233,0,53,139,14,0,0,0,0,0,2,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,4,95,105,112,112,4,95,116,99,112,5,108,111,99,97,108,0,
      0,12,0,1,5,95,105,112,112,115,192,17,0,12,0,1>>},
 {ethernet,<<1,0,94,0,0,251,0,80,86,192,0,8,8,0,69,0,0,73,68,44,0,0,255,17,
         18,106,172,16,216,1,224,0,0,251,20,233,20,233,0,53,139,14,0,0,0,
         0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,95,105,112,112,4,95,116,99,112,5,108,111,99,
         97,108,0,0,12,0,1,5,95,105,112,112,115,192,17,0,12,0,1>>}]
```

which I looking to convert into the readable format (I mean conversion of the binary holding list of integers into real representation the way Wireshark represent). My end goal is to wrap that readable content into a binary and share as JSON value.

Expected output format is below:

```
    0x0000:  4500 0049 442c 0000 ff11 126a ac10 d801  E..ID,.....j....
    0x0010:  e000 00fb 14e9 14e9 0035 8b0e 0000 0000  .........5......
    0x0020:  0002 0000 0000 0000 045f 6970 7004 5f74  ........._ipp._t
    0x0030:  6370 056c 6f63 616c 0000 0c00 0105 5f69  cp.local......_i
    0x0040:  7070 73c0 1100 0c00 01                   pps......
```

Comment: *conversion of the binary holding list of integers into real representation the way Wireshark represent* -- How about posting your desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Wireshark style Packet Dissection

Ages ago I was working with pcap data and wrote [Enet](https://github.com/archaelus/enet) to decode various common packet types.

You can use the `enet_codec:decode(eth, PktData, [{decode_types, all}])` to turn the data from your pcap frame into a readable packet:

```
Data = [{frame,1,
         {1491,213,861700},
         87,87,false,
         <<1,0,94,0,0,251,0,80,86,192,0,8,8,0,69,0,0,73,68,44,0,0,255,17,18,
           106,172,16,216,1,224,0,0,251,20,233,20,233,0,53,139,14,0,0,0,0,0,2,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,4,95,105,112,112,4,95,116,99,112,5,108,111,99,97,108,0,
           0,12,0,1,5,95,105,112,112,115,192,17,0,12,0,1>>},
        {ethernet,<<1,0,94,0,0,251,0,80,86,192,0,8,8,0,69,0,0,73,68,44,0,0,255,17,
                    18,106,172,16,216,1,224,0,0,251,20,233,20,233,0,53,139,14,0,0,0,
                    0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,95,105,112,112,4,95,116,99,112,5,108,111,99,
                    97,108,0,0,12,0,1,5,95,105,112,112,115,192,17,0,12,0,1>>}].

rr("include/enet_types.hrl"). % Load record definitions into the shell
PktData = element(7, hd(Data)). % Grab the ethernet frame binary
rp(enet_codec:decode(eth, element(7, hd(Data)), [{decode_types, all}])). % Decode and print

#eth{src = "00:50:56:C0:00:08",dst = "01:00:5E:00:00:FB",
     type = ipv4,
     data = #ipv4{vsn = 4,hlen = 5,diffserv = 0,totlen = 73,
                  id = 17452,flags = [],frag_offset = 0,ttl = 255,proto = udp,
                  hdr_csum = correct,
                  src = <<172,16,216,1>>,
                  dst = <<224,0,0,251>>,
                  options = [],
                  data = #udp{src_port = <<"mdns">>,dst_port = <<"mdns">>,
                              length = 53,
                              csum = {incorrect,35598},
                              data = [{dns_header,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                      [{dns_query,"_ipp._tcp.local",ptr,in},
                                       {dns_query,"_ipps._ipps._tcp.local",ptr,in}],
                                      [],[],[]]}}}
```

---

### Wireshark style Hexdump Output

Wireshark output conversely takes the raw packet data (or indeed pretty much any binary you care to feed it) and produces text output with offset, bytes printed in hex, and an ascii representation of the printable parts of the hex bytes.

`enet` contains `enet_if_dump:hexdump/` which does the same thing, so you can run:

```
Pkt = <<1,0,94,0,0,251,0,80,86,192,0,8,8,0,69,0,0,73,68,44,0,0,255,17,
        18,106,172,16,216,1,224,0,0,251,20,233,20,233,0,53,139,14,0,0,0,
        0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,95,105,112,112,4,95,116,99,112,5,108,111,99,
        97,108,0,0,12,0,1,5,95,105,112,112,115,192,17,0,12,0,1>>.

% This gives you a giant iolist with the formatted Wireshark style hexdump.
enet_if_dump:hexdump(Pkt).
% To inspect it you need to then do something like:
io:format("~s~n", [enet_if_dump:hexdump(Pkt)]). % which produces:

0x0000:  0100 5e00 00fb 0050 56c0 0008 0800 4500 ..^....PV.....E.
0x0010:  0049 442c 0000 ff11 126a ac10 d801 e000 .ID,.....j......
0x0020:  00fb 14e9 14e9 0035 8b0e 0000 0000 0002 .......5........
0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 045f 6970 7004 5f74 6370 ......._ipp._tcp
0x0040:  056c 6f63 616c 0000 0c00 0105 5f69 7070 .local......_ipp
0x0050:  73c0 1100 0c00 1                        s......
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I am not able to translate this entirely into below  format(like Wireshark represent).                                                        
        0x0000:  4500 0049 442c 0000 ff11 126a ac10 d801  E..ID,.....j....
        0x0010:  e000 00fb 14e9 14e9 0035 8b0e 0000 0000  .........5......
        0x0020:  0002 0000 0000 0000 045f 6970 7004 5f74  ........._ipp._t
        0x0030:  6370 056c 6f63 616c 0000 0c00 0105 5f69  cp.local......_i
        0x0040:  7070 73c0 1100 0c00 01                   pps......

Comment: Oh - do you want like a hexdump of the raw bytes or something? `enet_if_dump:hexblock(PktData)` does the offset and hex printing bit. You could extend that code to print the ascii version after each line of hex to get the format you mention in the comment.